# Symbol to indicate normalized or standardized variables

Tags: normalization, standardization, notation

Is there a symbol to indicate that variables have been standardized?

For example, if I have 2 different scoring functions ***Score1*** and ***Score2***. Let's say I want to form a combo score and show that the scores have been standardized, e.g.,

\[ \text{ComboScore1} = \frac{\text{std. Score1} + \text{std. Score2}}{2} \]

two differentiate from a flavor of a ComboScore where the individual scores have not been standardized

\[ \text{ComboScore2} = \frac{\text{Score1} + \text{Score2}}{2} \]

Comment: You are right, I removed the tag

Comment: How are you standardizing exactly? Are these standardized for sample mean and standard deviation, or in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standards can vary from one application area to another.

Speaking for myself, I'd probably do something this:

Let $z_1 = \frac{\text{score}_1-\text{?}}{\text{??}}$ (depending on how you're standardizing, I'd fill in the missing parts differently) and similarly for $z_2$. Then

\[ \text{ComboScore}_1 = \frac{z_1 + z_2}{2} \]

Which is to say I'd explicitly (algebraically) define the z-scores, then explicitly algebraically define the combo score.

Comment: Yes, I would mention in the prepending text something like "after standardization (z-score normalization) of the individual scores, the combo score is calculated as follows [ComboScore equation]." That's a good idea, I will just add also something like $Score1_z = \frac{Score1_i - \bar{Score1}}{\sigma_{Score1}}$

Comment: Conventially, $\overline{x}$ indicates a sample mean of $x_i$'s, while $\sigma_x$ indicates a *population* standard deviation. If you know the population s.d. how is it you don't know the mean?

Comment: I am confused now, where did I say that I don't know the mean?

Comment: The fact that you use a sample mean to standardize rather than the population mean implies you don't know the population mean. If you knew the population parameters, you'd use $\frac{x_i-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}$. If you only had sample quantities you'd used $\frac{x_i-\bar x}{s_x}$. You mixed the two (sample mean, population sd), which leads to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, how would you indicate that $\sigma_{score1}$ is the sample standard deviation and not the population S.D. Based on your edit, you suggest to use "s" rather than $\sigma$ for sample standard deviation vs. population standard deviation?

Comment: The answer to that should be fairly clear from the fact that I used $s_x$ for the sample standard deviation of $x$ in my previous comment... it would be $s_{\text{score}_1}$. The use of $s$ for sample standard deviations is pretty conventional. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation) for example.